# ModelViewSet Queryset Filter with table based value with another table

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

I have two tables in my database `ProductStock` and `Sales`.And I am storing the Product info in the `ProductStock` table and Sales info inside the `Sales` table.

Based on the total sum of sold quantity I want to filter the data, and return the data only whose quantity is greater than **0**.

for eg.

> **PRODUCT STOCK DATA**

| ID | PRODUCT | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Django Course | 50 |
| 2 | Social Codia | 50 |

> **SALES DATA**

| PRODUCT_STOCK_ID | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 2 | 10 |

Here the sold quantity of product **1** is `5+45=50`, that means there is no stock left in the database for product **1**.

**QUESTION IN SHORT :** How can i fetch all these products whose quantity is greater than `current_quantity - sold_quantity`  greater than **0**.

**My ProductStock Model**

```
class ProductStock(Core):
    medical = models.ForeignKey(Medical, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    distributer = models.ForeignKey(Distributer,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='product')
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Attribute,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
    purchase_price = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)    
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    low_stock = models.IntegerField(default=10,null=False,blank=False)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False,blank=False)
```

**My SALE Model**

```
class Sale(Core):
    product_stock = models.ForeignKey(ProductStock,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='sales')
    medical = models.ForeignKey(Medical,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='medical')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1,null=False,blank=False)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,blank=False)
    discount = models.FloatField(max_length=10,default=0)
```

**ProductStockViewSet**

```
class ProductStockViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductStockSerializer
    permission_classes  = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductStock.objects.all()
```

To deal with the issue I have overridden the `list` of `ProductStockViewSet`, by using a for loop fetching every single product's total sold quantity, and by subscripting it with  actual quantity i am getting the current quantity.

But I know this could not be a good solution to fetch data like these.

```
def list(self,request,pk=None):
    products = ProductStock.objects.all()
    for product in products:
        quantities = Sale.objects.filter(product_stock=product).aggregate(quantities = Sum('quantity')).get('quantities')
        if quantities is not None:
            current_quantity = product.quantity - quantities
            print(f'QUANTITY : {product.quantity} ==== SOLD QUANTITY : {quantities} ==== CURRENT QUANTITY : {current_quantity}' ,)
            product.quantity = current_quantity
            
    serializer = ProductStockSerializer(products,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: Appears to me that you need to do it in a few queries (at least 2). What have you tried and any observations if you did try something?

Comment: Yeah. You can seen that overridden list method. To solve the I had tries that.

Comment: But right now I am thinking to update the sales count any stock table. Instead of fetching all record  then  subscript it. Will it be good solution to solve the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query you wanted:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

ProductStock.objects.alias(
    quantity_sold=Sum('sales__quantity')
).filter(
    quantity_sold__lt=F('quantity')
)
```

* default values for null and blank parameters of fields is False, so no need to pass `null=False, blank=False` to every field you make.

Comment: We have modified our schema. So not using these condition anymore

Comment: What is your suggestion. which one option will be good.
1) Decreasing the stock available quantity on sell.
2) Fetching the thousand of sold product quantity then perform mathematics to get the current available quantity.

Comment: @mufazmi personally, i prefer the second option, so i can keep history of sales better. I think quantity field of sales was a good choice.

Comment: Thankyou @Amrez For your feedback.
I also love the second option. But i think it will take longer time to fetch the record than first option.
right.?

Comment: @mufazmi i think compared to the main query, its time can be ignored. But right, the second option should takes longer